Maven pdf:pdf ignores asciidoc files
I am generating system documentation with mvn site and it works fine with mixed file formats (as intended with mvn site). We have both asciidoc and markdown in the same file structure.
Recently I added the Maven PDF plugin (mvn pdf:pdf) and it generates a PDF without the content from asciidoc files, it is simply ignoring the files even though they are bundled in the tmp directories for the PDF file generation itself.
Is there a way to get asciidoc to be generated into the PDF that the PDF Plugin generates?
Or do I have to abandon markdown completely and use the Asciidoc Plugin to generate PDFs?

Why not using asciidoctor-maven-plugin instead?

That's an option and it comes with the task to convert all existing markdown files to adoc.
